# Most Recent Nifty GUI Initialization

Tags: java, lwjgl, nifty-gui

I am trying to get going with Nifty GUI since I like the whole design and function separation (coming from android). I tried to follow the tutorial [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nifty-gui/index.php?title=Hello_World_Example) but I get tons of errors (the libs are all correctly imported.

All the errors are `cannot find symbol for Render Device, SlickSoundDevice, LwglInitHelper, etc...`

I looked around a bit and it says that with every nifty iteration the init changes. What is the current one?

Libs I have in my project:

- LWJGL 2.9.0
- Slick (newest, downloaded 9/29/2013)
- Nifty GUI 1.3.3
- xpp3 1.1.4.c

Answer (score 2):

Currently the best way to learn about Nifty is the [1.3.2 PDF manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/files/nifty-gui/1.3.2/nifty-gui-the-manual-1.3.2.pdf/download).

You'll probably need more jars in your classpath, especially the LWJGL-Renderer and maybe the default controls jar as well but the manual explains that all in more detail.

You might want to take a look at the examples in the github repository too, especially the [Hello World example](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/1.3/nifty-examples/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldExampleMain.java) code. You can find the required dependencies in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/1.3/nifty-examples/pom.xml) of the examples project. And yes, the wiki is kinda outdated. Sorry about that!

Comment: Which is now the stable? 1.4?

Comment: Nifty 1.3.3 is the latest stable version at the time of this comment :)

Comment: Nifty 1.4 is the latest stable version at the time of this comment :)

Comment: Why is there nifty jwjgl slick render 1.3 only and all other packages are on 1.4.1..? Is it still on development ?

Comment: I think the "nifty lwjgl slick" renderer is outdated and has now been seperated into a "lwjgl" or a "slick" renderer. So you can now decide between pure lwjgl or pure slick2d. The wiki is outdated and haven't been updated yet. You might want to use the pdf manual which is somewhat more accurate and most of the information is still valid for 1.4.1.